# MySQL Insert Query with Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a value in table glmast in the field called acname.

The conditions I am using is as follows

```
g.gl_id = p.gl_id AND p.pl_id='$pdidedit' with g as glmast and p as packlist
```

I tried joins, and try the below code..

```
INSERT INTO glmast (acname)
VALUES
('$glidnew') SELECT glmast.acname WHERE glmast.gl_id = packlist.gl_id AND packlist='$pdidedit'";
```

Any help highly appreciated..Thanks everyone..

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Is `INSERT INTO .. VALUES .. SELECT` valid syntax ?

Comment: I tried in phpadmin with some input values.. It didn't execute..@ajtrichards Thanks for replyin :)

Comment: @karthikr - no it's not valid. Skip the value and it would be.. almost...

Comment: @karthikr I don't think so.. That is why I wanted to know..Any idea??

Comment: @user2234992 - what exactly are your trying to achieve with your sql?

Comment: INSERT is for adding new rows. Are you trying to modify an existing row? You must use UPDATE for that.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld just insert a value in glmast table with the conditions above.. This conditions involves foreign keys of two table..Thanks for your interest..

Comment: There's no `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses in your `SELECT`. What is `$glidnew` supposed to be?

Comment: @Barmar Yes I tried joins..I didn't get it.. $glidnew is some post value I'll be getting..thanks

Comment: Is `$glidnew` something you want to insert into the table? What column should it be inserted into?

Comment: @glidnew is the main value I want to insert in table glmast..Thanks..

Comment: @user2234992 - I believ I understand your question (or not ;-) I supplied an answer.

Comment: If none of our answers do what you want, can you show some sample input data and the desired result? Best would be to make a sqlfiddle.

Comment: I use the same condition for updating, So I thought this will work with insert as well..May be I am wrong..I'll figure that out..Thank you all for your help..

Answer (score 2):

You can write insert like

```
INSERT INTO glmast (acname) VALUES ('$glidnew');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO glmast (acname)
SELECT glmast.acname from glmast,packlist 
  WHERE glmast.gl_id = packlist.gl_id
    AND packlist.gl_id = '$pdidedit'";
```

Have in mind that in second example there could be multiple inserts in cases when select returns multiple rows.

Comment: There's no `VALUES` keyword when you're using a `SELECT` as the data.

Comment: @user2234992, first make simple select which returns value which you want for `acname`. After that, you can use insert like in second example.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you're trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO glmast(gl_id, acname)
SELECT '$glidnew', glmast.acname
FROM glmast JOIN packlist ON glmast.gl_id = packlist.gl_id
WHERE packlist.pl_id='$pdidedit'
```

You keep saying INSERT, but I'm pretty sure you mean UPDATE:

```
UPDATE glmast g
JOIN packlist p ON g.gl_id = p.gl_id
SET g.acname = '$glidnew'
WHERE p.pl_id = '$pdidedit'
```

Or maybe this is it:

```
INSERT INTO glmast (acname, col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT '$glidnew', g.col1, g.col2, g.col3, ...
FROM glmast g
JOIN packlist p ON g.gl_id = p.gl_id
WHERE p.pl_id = '$pdidedit'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. I want $glidnew inserted into acname field of glmast table..Hope am clear..Thanks again

Comment: Then what are you using `select glmast.acname` for? Are you sure you don't want to UPDATE rather than INSERT?

Comment: yes It is a insert to a new row..That is how I need it be done.. @Barmer

Comment: Are you trying to copy all the other fields of the new row from the row that matches the conditions?

Comment: @user2234992 - if you insert something to a new row in DB you can't just update ONE column to that new row. You have to insert all columns that exists in your table.

Comment: Maybe my latest edit is what you want. This is like pulling teeth trying to get you to explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

***I belive it's something like this you're trying to achieve***:

```
INSERT INTO glmast (acname) VALUES('$glidnew')
WHERE (
    SELECT glmast.acname FROM glmast GM
    JOIN packlist PL ON (PL.gl_id = GM.gl_id)
    WHERE PL.pl_id='$pdidedit'
)
```

But that syntax is not valid in MySQL.
You will have to run the SELECT-statement first, and then INSERT into the glmast table based on resultset given from SELECT-query:

**Step 1:**

```
SELECT glmast.acname FROM glmast GM
JOIN packlist PL ON (PL.gl_id = GM.gl_id)
WHERE PL.pl_id='$pdidedit'
```

**Step 2:**

```
INSERT INTO glmast (acname) VALUES({values from Step1})
```

In a way, you can say that `$glidnew` represents the values from Step1.

Comment: Why a LEFT JOIN? And you're not using `$glidnew` in step 1 or step 2.

Comment: @Barmar - of course it should not be left join. Thanks (I'm using that most, so it was just a habit :-)) $glidnew is the same as the values from step1. I have to clarify that.